# Computed property depending on ALL properties of @each

Tags: ember.js

I've used before the type of computed property that looks like this:

```
isAnyoneHungry: function () {
  var everyone = this.get('everyone'),
      anyoneHungry = false;
  everyone.forEach(function(person) {
    if (person.get('isHungry')) {
      anyoneHungry = true;
    }
  });
  return anyoneHungry;
}.property('everyone.@each.isHungry'),

everyone: Ember.A() // an array that will hold person models
```

for computing something based on one property of each object in an array.

Is it possible to make a computed property based on *every* property of each object in an array? 
Say that the `person` model has many boolean properties like `isHungry`, `isTired`, `isCranky`, ... and I want to be able to recompute this property when any one of those changes. But I'm lazy and don't want to type every single property like this:

`function(){...}.property('everyone.@each.isHungry', 'everyone.@each.isTired', 'everyone.@each.isCranky'.`

Instead I'd like something like this:

```
isAnyoneUnhappy: function () {
  var everyone = this.get('everyone'),
      isAnyoneUnhappy = false;
  everyone.forEach(function (person) {
    if (person.get('isHungry') || person.get('isTired') || person.get('isCranky')) {
      isAnyoneUnhappy = true;
    }
  });
  return isAnyoneUnhappy;
}.property('everyone.@each.iWantEveryPropertyHere')
```

Is this possible in Ember yet?

Comment: i can't get this simple fiddle to work, adding it here for convenience because it's directly related to this question.  i can't get the computed property to fire despite using the @each.attributeName notation: http://jsfiddle.net/a2cxg/1/

Comment: I have trouble getting jsfiddle to play nice with frameworks sometimes, but the problem is that unlike observers, a computed property doesn't automatically get called whenever its listed sub-properties change. You'd have to call `someObject.get('changeWatcher')` or convert it to an `observer` instead of a `property`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
isAnyoneUnhappy: function () {
  var everyone = this.get('everyone'),
      isAnyoneUnhappy = false;
  everyone.forEach(function (person) {
    if (person.get('isHungry') || person.get('isTired') || person.get('isCranky')) {
      isAnyoneUnhappy = true;
    }
  });
  return isAnyoneUnhappy;
}.property('everyone.@each.*')
```

I looked into the Ember source and there seems to be some logic dealing with the star notation. I am not sure though.

Comment: Tried that out just now and doesn't seem to work. This is exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should have a property on person that rolls up the unhappy attributes, something like:

```
isUnhappy: function () {
  if (this.get('isHungry') || this.get('isTired') || this.get('isCranky')) {
    return true;
  }
}.property('isTired', 'isHungry', 'isCranky')
```

Then `isAnyoneUnhappy` just observes `everyone.@each.isUnhappy`

Comment: I agree this is an ideal solution. I am trying to come up with a way to get around having to provide all of the names of the properties being depended on. There could be very many properties you want to list there, or you may not know what all they are if you are dynamically generating properties.

Comment: better: `return this.get('isHungry') || this.get('isTired') || this.get('isCranky')` (false -> no return value)